# How can I add a new form in "Share : " part in News Feed menu?

Tags: facebook

I'm trying to develop a Facebook application that has some connectivity to Facebook.
When I click 'News Feed menu', 'Share:Status Photo Link Video Question' appears on the top. 
I'd like to add another option that interacts with my own Facebook appliction.

Question 1. Is there a specific term that refers to this 'Share:Status Photo Link Video Question' part?

Question 2. Can I add a new option? How?

Question 3. Can I customize the form? (for example, URL edit box and Attatch button appears when we click 'Link' button) How?

Any information will be appreciated :)